# How to select the cell referred by the active cell in excel?

Tags: excel, select, reference, keyboard-shortcuts, cell

Suppose i am in a cell with value *=A3*, then, is there a way or shortcut key to select cell **A3**? or if it contains reference to multiple cell such as *=A3+A4*, then, i want **A3** and **A4** selected, and so on...

This can be helpful if the reference cell are in other sheets. I work in an excel sheet in which almost all the values are linked to other cells (most of the time other sheets), and the cell again referenced to the other. So, finding the cell with value in it (using the references) takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Trace Precedents feature on the Formula Auditing tab of the Formulas ribbon.

If the Precedent is on the same worksheet, clicking the arrow head will take you there.

If the Precedent is on another worksheet, clicking the arrow head in the formula box will bring up a "GoTo" dialog box, that will then enable you to navigate to the other worksheet cell.

[image]